# Under which entry should example phrases be included in a bilingual dictionary?

Tags: phrases, lexicography, examples

I am currently working on a thematic bilingual dictionary and I'm having trouble deciding under which entry the sample phrases I find in my corpus should be listed.

For instance, should translations for "religious war" be placed under "religious" (adj.) or "war" (n.)? The same question arises for many noun phrases ("prime minister") and verb phrases ("to give a speech"). An especially difficult case is that of "proof by contradiction".
I've consulted several dictionaries and academic articles on bilingual dictionaries, but I have not found a definitive answer as they provide contradictory usage.

Comment: prime minister is a term in and of itself; religous war is not, as there are others types of wars. I use bilingual dictionaries all the time but frankly am too lazy to check them all out. Again, proof by contradiction is not "a" term, just like religious war.

Answer (score 6):

There is no one-size-fits-all answer to this. You’ll have to ask yourself where the user is more likely to look, which will often be little more than guesswork.

There are a few very basic rules of thumb, but you still need to use common sense before applying them:

- Users (at least those who have experience using dictionaries) are generally speaking more likely to look under the head word: for ‘religious war’, they’d be more likely to look under *war*, and for ‘prime minister’, they’d be more likely to look under *minister*.
- If one of the elements is a particularly common word (like *give* in ‘give a speech’), and the other is less common (like *speech*), it is often better to put it under the less common word, since entries like *give* tend to be very long already, and examples are easy to miss in very long entries.
- If the entry is a very tightly-knit compound, it is sometimes a good idea to include the compound as a separate entry; many English-language dictionaries include *prime minister* as an entry, for example.

Of course, you also have to remember that bilingual dictionaries have two major groups of users: speakers of the source language learning the target language, and speakers of the target language learning the source language. Members of these two groups may not look the same place for the same thing.

Let’s say your dictionary is English–Warlpiri as an example.

A native English speaker looking for the Warlpiri word for ‘prime minister’ will likely either look directly for the compound as an entry or look under *minister*. I would not expect an English speaker to look under *prime* except as a last resort.

A Warlpiri speaker who comes across the term and already knows what *minister* means (but not what *prime* means) will likely first look under *prime*, since that’s the word they don’t understand. If the compound is not listed there and they can’t guess the meaning from the combination of *prime* and *minister* separately, they will likely also look under *minister* under the assumption that a prime minister must be a type of minister. If they know what *prime* means (but not *minister*), they will obviously most likely do it the other way around, with *minister* first and *prime* second if necessary.

A Warlpiri speaker who knows neither word will likely look them up in the order they appear in the text; they will find the compound wherever it’s listed, but faster if it’s listed under *prime*.

In a case like this, my advice would be to **include the compound under both entries**. Cross references from one entry to the other are also useful, especially if the translation is not simple and straightforward.

Comment: Thank you for providing these guidelines

Comment: I would never put "prime minister" under two different entries. Collins online (monolingual) has it just like that. But I would put prime and minister under two separate entries. Anyway, this is not about what a user is likely to look up but what a dictionary is likely to list.  The Harrap's French>English dictionary does not list premier ministre at all. And neither does the français-anglais Larousse online.

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries give unpredictable / idiosyncratic properties of words such as irregular plurals (not regular plurals). In the case of "give a speech", it is most useful to list this under "give" because there are a number of "give an X" idioms, and for language learners it would be particularly useful to know that "speech; lecture; talk; example" can be idiomatically used whereas "give a car" is literally about giving a car.

The two parts of "prime minister" are sufficiently non-compositional that one could reasonably list the compound under both parts (contrasting education, defense, revenue and other kinds of ministers, as well as other senses of primeness like "prime example; prime number; prime directive". The question that a user would be asking is, what other kinds of minister can there be, or what other things can be prime? I don't see any strong reason to include "religious war" in a dictionary (maybe I'm missing something obvious). Many things can be "about religion" and wars can be motivated by all words of properties. I guess "Land war" is actually ambiguous in that it either means "fought on the ground as opposed to at se or in the air", or can refer to a specific war known in Irish as Cogadh na Talún.

Comment: I would say the more useful place to put _give a speech_ would be under _speech_. I’m not likely to look up one of the most common verbs in the language and wonder what nouns that verb might take as its object; but if I know the word for a speech, I would be quite likely to also want to know which verb it collocates with. Is it to speak a speech? To say a speech? To hold a speech? To talk a speech? To act a speech? To do a speech? — No, it’s to _give_ a speech.

Comment: If you look up speech in the French< English Harrap's for instance: faire un discours [speech] comes right after the term *discours*, followed by other uses starting with discours.